# Google Wallet integration on a multi user system

Tags: python, django, payment, android-pay, gateways

I have a small issue right now where I am trying to integrate Google wallet with my project which has many users which will all have access to using this gateway and accepting payments.

The only issue I cannot seem to over come or figure out how to get around is how am I supposed to know which sellers secret key to use for the encoded JWT I receive from the postback?

Since I cannot access the the data inside the JWT obviously without decoding it first?

Thanks to anyone who can help me brainstorm about trying to work around this.

------UPDATE------
By the looks of what I have here, could I use the success or failure call back handlers to associate my users with the encoded JWT and then then compare the JWT to a database and call the corosponding users data to decode the JWT?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either

- `aud`
- `sellerData`

from Google's [`postback`](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/postback#jwt) and obtain the `Seller Id`...

So something like:

1. Base64url  decode JWT to get the Seller Id from either `aud` or `sellerData`
2. do your lookup for stored seller secret
3. verify the JWT

Hth....

Comment: The postback is simply the JWT encoded still so that would not work, you have to get the success handler from the jquery to post to a url a id to be able to pull the data required from the database and decode the JWT to be able to access the data. After digging through the post data i noticed this.

Comment: @SamBuckingham I'm probably missing something in your question...you need to (aren't you?) verify the JWT postback before it gets to your (client side) handlers.

Comment: No you dont need to verify it on the client side you verify it on the server side actually, but you use the client side data to verify the server side.

Comment: @SamBuckingham That's what I'm referring to - the _first_ verification happens _server side_ (the `postback` from Google). Depending on how this goes (server side), either your _success_ or _failure_ callbacks are called. The final step, which is an additional check/verification, then goes from client -> server (at which point you have a `Google Order Id`). Does this help/clarify?